# Calculating CRC32 checksum of a file

Tags: linux, perl, crc32

I'm trying to **calculate CRC32 check sum of a file** to use with this module [Mod_zip](https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip), I tried to do this with `PHP` but unfortunately failed, even if passed won't be efficient for larger files.

I also tried `linux cksum` command but it calculates CRC checksum of the file.

I found that **perl** on **linux** can be used to calculate CRC32 of a file, if this is possible I could use shell_exec to import the output onto my `PHP` application, how can I do this?

Comment: CRC32 isn't a single, unique algorithm.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC32#Commonly_used_and_standardized_CRCs  That page lists 12 different variants, and that's before considering preconditioning and postconditioning.

Comment: @JoeZ - There only one `CRC-32` listed on that page.

Comment: @Kenosis : There are 4 common CRC-32s listed (with different suffix letters, yes), and for each of the four CRC-32s, there are three variants of the polynomial listed (forward, reverse and reversed reciprocal).  When you cross those with big-endian/little-endian, 0s vs 1s precondition, inverted/non-inverted post-condition, it's a mess.  Digest::CRC ( http://search.cpan.org/~olimaul/Digest-CRC-0.18/lib/Digest/CRC.pm ) handles all of these, I believe, but its documentation is lacking.

Comment: @Kenosis : Note that if your goal is "a checksum that matches ZIP" (or some other specific program), that's a bit more bounded.  I believe the `crc32` method in Digest::CRC will do that, as that is the most common CRC-32 people ask for.  (I've just been burned, as I've seen waaaaay too many CRC implementations in the embedded world.)

Comment: @JoeZ - "There are 4 common CRC-32s..."  The OP specified CRC32 and not one of its variants.  [Digest::CRC](http://search.cpan.org/~olimaul/Digest-CRC-0.18/lib/Digest/CRC.pm) does CRC-32, as you've mentioned. [String::CRC32](http://search.cpan.org/~soenke/String-CRC32-1.4/CRC32.pod) also does CRC-32.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [Digest::CRC](http://search.cpan.org/~olimaul/Digest-CRC-0.18/lib/Digest/CRC.pm)?  From the documentation: "It contains wrapper functions with the correct parameters for CRC-CCITT, CRC-16, CRC-32 and CRC-64, as well as the CRC used in OpenPGP's ASCII-armored checksum."

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::CRC;

my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new( type => 'crc32' );

open my $fh, '<:raw', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
$ctx->addfile(*$fh);
close $fh;

print $ctx->hexdigest, "\n";
```

Command-line usage: `perl script.pl inFile`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but this calculates the CRC value of the file not CRC32, CRC32 is 8 digit but this returns 10 digits.

Comment: @NaveenGamage - Were you looking for the hexdigest?  That returns 8 hex digits. This *is* the CRC-32 for files.  Have modified the code to show the hexdigest.

Comment: @NaveenGamage - "0x" only denotes that a hexadecimal number follows; it's not part of the checksum.  Normal CRC-32 has 8 hexadecimal digits: 0x********  The `$ctx->hexdigest` above returns this.

Comment: yes I get it now, even the mod_zip module takes CRC32 value without 0x. thank you for helping me.